# How to take the result from if condition out of it?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, logic

I would like to ask something about python logic and how could i solve this problem.
Here is my code:

```
controlRatio = 1
for i in range(10):
    if controlRatio == 1:
        if (i%2==1):
            print(i)
    elif controlRatio == 2:
        print(i)
    #code#
    #Because my code long is and i don't want to write the code below if and also below elif.
    #I would like to take the result from the condition and use it below the 'for'. 
    In my case this would be either 13579 or 0123456789
```

How could i take the 'i' result out of the if condition and use it.
I tried with a variable, but it doesn't work as i expected

Comment: `if controlRatio == 1 & i%2==1`

Answer (score 0):

declare the value of i to another variable in the if statement of your choice. then you can use the variable. in this example "tmp". you could also save all the values for i in a list and add every new element with <list_name>.append(i)

```
tmp = 0                         #the variable
controlRatio = 1
for i in range(10):
    if controlRatio == 1:
        if (i%2==1):
            print(i)
            tmp = i             #the variable
    elif controlRatio == 2:
        print(i) 
´´´
```